# Possible to configure database autogrowth settings at the instance level?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Basically I would like to have all databases in a certain instance have the same autogrow settings.  Is it possible to set this at the instance level so that I don't need to go into each database and configure it?

Comment: Take a look at my answer:  
http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24172/11530

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any user database you create inherits it's base settings from the system model database. Set the size and autogrowth settings in model and each database you create from then on will have the same configuration.

Comment: I have read in several places that default settings for a new db should be based on model, but for autogrowth it appears this only happens by clicking new database in SQL Management studio UI and not from a script e.g. CREATE DATABASE [MyDb]. 

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1065073-391-1.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388(v=sql.105).aspx

Has anyone actually got this to work with a create script?